# Strange issue with NetworkStream and reading the first two bytes of a message

Tags: c#, sockets

I am running into this strange issue where reading the first two bytes of a TCP message can take 5-10 seconds (after accepting the connection) but reading the rest of the message is almost instant.

This only seems to occur when receiving requests from an external integrator, no issues with reading requests from inside the network or even from my computer at home. Because of that I am assuming it is a network issue with us and them.

An network issue could take forever to resolve so I am hoping there is something I could fix with my code.

```cs
NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

byte[] lengthHeader = new byte[2];
stream.Read(lengthHeader, 0, 2);
int length = lengthHeader[0] * 256 + lengthHeader[1];

byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
```

Comment: It's not your code. What you see is the time for the 1st package ( >>> 2 bytes) to arrive.

Comment: There are all kinds of buffers involved. By the time the first `Read` returns, there may be much more data just sitting in a buffer waiting to be returned by subsequent calls. Also, your code is broken - you're not checking the return value from `Read`, and so you're e.g. assuming that `lengthHeader[1]` is a valid byte when that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Okay. I was worried that wasn't the case. That there might be something weird with calling stream.Read for the first two bytes followed by the full length recieved.

Comment: @John - make sure you've read and understood the second part of my comment - any call to `Read` may have only provided as little as *one* byte (assuming the connection is still active) - it doesn't matter what's happened at the other end of the connection in terms of `Write` calls. So make sure that you recode to make repeated `Read` calls until you've accumulated a complete message

Comment: Well in my original code I had it working like that for the body of the message, which was reading using beginread. I didn't think I would need it for 2 byte header, that kind complicates things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

Was a miscommunication issue between me and the other guy. Turns out he was expecting a persistent socket connection.